# Javascript: Adding a condition to 'Page Leave Confirmation'?

Tags: javascript, html

I figured out how to show a 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?' confirmation dialog if a user leaves a web page. It works. Now I need to figure out how to trigger this dialog ONLY IF the user has typed something into an input field in my page.

The following code works. But it triggers every time the user tries to leave the page:

**Confirmation Listener Function:**

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?'
                            + 'We hope you had a great experience!';

    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE

    return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="storyBox" type="text" />
```

I need to check if the user typed in any text to the input field **and decide whether to trigger** the leave confirmation dialog or not:

```
if(document.getElementById("storyBox").value.length != 0){
    //Trigger the Event Listener
}
```

My question is, **where do I place this condition**? Obviously surrounding the EventListener with the condition won't work. How can I trigger this event **only if the input field is not empty**?

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar comments aren't for answers!

Comment: Sorry, I did that because I was not 100% sure about the answer and in fear that I'd get a downvote @N.J.Dawson

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar I was mostly moaning because comments murder any formatting you add to it, but for future reference I'd say put yourself out there and post an answer, I'm sure you'll pander a few upvotes, I'd say stackoverflow is a friendly community! :)

Comment: Okay..!! I'll surely take a chance next time!! @N.J.Dawson Infact my answer was exactly same as iuliu.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't return from inside the eventListener the pop-up won't show, so you can do this:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    if(document.getElementById("storyBox").value.length != 0){
        var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?'
                            + 'We hope you had a great experience!';

        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE

        return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eunmyz2j/)

(When you click the 'Run' button a `beforeunload` is raised. So you can test it.)

Comment: Thanks for the ridiculously simple solution. Such a shame I couldn't see what was right in front of me ;)

Comment: No browser need the return value to continue ? Just to be sure ;)

Comment: Is this safe? Do browsers require a return in functions like this?

Comment: No problem, if you leave out the *return*, the function returns *undefined* by default

Answer (score 1):

this code is simple but it will work

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?'
                        + 'We hope you had a great experience!';
  if(document.getElementById("storyBox").value.length != 0){
return confirmationMessage;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var confirmMessage = function (e) {
        var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?'
                    + 'We hope you had a great experience!';

        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE

        return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
    };

    function bindEvent(element){
        if(document.getElementById("storyBox").value.length != 0){
            window.addEventListener("beforeunload", confirmMessage);
        }
        else {
            window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", confirmMessage);
        }

    };
```

This will also work. This remove the eventListener when no text in the input. and add the eventListner there are text inside the text box